# How to use quantity picker in Shopify's post purchase extension?

Tags: shopify

I saw a quantity picker in their [UX guidelines](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/checkout/product-offers/post-purchase/ux-guidelines/upsell) page. They also have a section for [quantity picker](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/checkout/product-offers/post-purchase/ux-guidelines/upsell#quantity-picker) in that page. But, that thing does not help me. They did not specify which component I should use to achieve. I also looked at [Components](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-extensions/components) page. That page also does not contain something that I can use to increase or decrease quantity.

I also tried using `Stepper` from `@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react` package. But I am getting `Stepper is not valid component` type error.